# In-app purchase confusion in iPhone: is it possible to use both type of in-app purchases in a single application?

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

I have an application which is using a consumable in app purchase for the products. Now I want to add some more portions to the existing application which can be used only if the user is subscribed for that option. So is it possible to use both type of inapp purchases in a single application. And can anybody provide an idea about how I can achieve this.

Comment: What do you mean by subscribe? A once of payment to be added to a list, or a month by month thing. I believe both are possible.

Comment: i need month by month subscription for totally different resources.it has a different section.nothing related with consumable resources

Comment: can u help me with snipets of code that i need to add to my mkstoremanagerclass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just go to iTunes Connect, to your app, and then to manage in-app purchase section.

You can add any amount of purchases there. Then your new in-app will be reviewd by Apple and you would be able to update your app with new code for retrieving that new in-app.

Answer (score 2):

So you want to hide some in apps unless they have purchased a special in app?
Can't you just check in your code if the first one has been bought? Then display the rest.

Comment: i mean not like that. i want to add an extra inapp for a seperate section to the next version of this app.can u give me an idea how to add an extra in app in appstore by keeping the existing one in appstore